# Matching characters from 2 lists with strings

Tags: python, string, list, match, character

using python I'd like to do the following

```py
list1 = ['some text from a string (yes it is here too)', 'some more text 2', 'some more text 3 (with some parenthesis)']

list2 = ['string (yes it is here too)', 'text 2', '(with some parenthesis)']
```

and produce the following list:

```py
list3 = ['some text from a', 'some more', 'some more text 3']
```

What is the best method to do this in python 3?

Comment: You want to make a new list and add strings from both the lists, if the string doesn't have parenthesis?

Comment: Does the text in `list2` entries always appear at the end of the corresponding `list1` entries?

Comment: I am looking to pattern match specific words and keep parts of sentences using one of the lists (list2) as the set of items id like to remove from list1.  Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If items in list2 are always shorter (a part of) items in list1. You can do this:

```
list3 = []
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
    list3.append(''.join(i.split(j)))
```

Or in one line:

```
list3 = [''.join(i.split(j)) for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
```

If number of items in list2 are not equal to items in list1, all of the appearance of list2 items can be removed from list1 items like this:

```
list3 = []
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if j in i:
            i = ''.join(i.split(j))
    list3.append(i)
```

Comment: Here are 2 real lists I'm dealing with:

Comment: list1 = ['Creamiest mac and cheese: 2:08 + 2:16 (end at 1:55 after “running joke in this house”) + 2:25 + 1:02', 'Southern Baked Beans: 4:48 (end at 4:17 after “see what we’ve got”) + 2:29 (end at 0:48ish after she takes the bite and says “mmm”) + 0:42 (start at 0:10 with “so this’ll be great”; end at 0:29 after “see y’all soon” and before she tries and fails to eat it)']

Comment: list2 = ['(end at 1:55 after “running joke in this house”)', '(end at 4:17 after “see what we’ve got”), (end at 0:48ish after she takes the bite and says “mmm”), (start at 0:10 with “so this’ll be great”; end at 0:29 after “see y’all soon” and before she tries and fails to eat it)']

Comment: the above solution didn't seem to return the right value for list3 which is strange.

Comment: You are right. I edited it. Check it out now. Last code would only remove from the end of the string

Comment: It worked for the first list item!  I think I have to group my list items better, that's the issue.  I am matching via regEx to get these lists generated however I need to find a way to group items from the same line via python regEx selection (which is what these items would have in common).

Comment: I don't know if it works in all cases but here you can split the string by comma.

Comment: See my lists below, I was able to get them grouped but it only works on the first list item and not the rest.

Comment: You didn't group them; you just removed commas. you should split second string by commas and add new strings to the list. like this: list2 += list2[1].split(',').

Comment: After you split second string, number of items in list2 will be more than number of items in list1 and then you can use the new code I added above.

Comment: Apologies (I'm a novice coder and not sure how to implement this in a loop), I was thinking of somehow doing this like: for i in list2:
        list2 =+ list2[i].split(',')
    print(list2)

Comment: But that doesn't work since the list indices is a string

Comment: That is not right. try this: for i in range(len(list2)):
    list2 += list2[i].split(',')

Comment: Ok actually I am getting close, I used your updated solution above, however list1, each item is a string and list2 each item is a list (of the strings for each line), what is the best way to match them so that I can get them to properly compare?

Comment: No, in both lists all items should be strings. split list2 by comma and use my second code above and every thing should be fine. using '+=' will add all string in the splited list to list2.

Comment: It worked!  For list2 I used [''.join(x) for x in remove_parenthesis] to prep it before your split statement and then ran it though, how cool!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this homemade recipe.

```
list1 = ['some text from a string (yes it is here too)', 'some more text 2', 'some more text 3 (with some parenthesis)']

list2 = ['string (yes it is here too)', 'text 2', '(with some parenthesis)']
need = [[space for space in l1.split(l2) if space != ''] for l1,l2 in zip(list1,list2)]
```

Comment: It worked for the first list item but not the others in my list, I've organized the lists as follows:

Comment: list1 = ['Creamiest mac and cheese: 2:08 + 2:16 (end at 1:55 after “running joke in this house”) + 2:25 + 1:02', 'Southern Baked Beans: 4:48 (end at 4:17 after “see what we’ve got”) + 2:29 (end at 0:48ish after she takes the bite and says “mmm”) + 0:42 (start at 0:10 with “so this’ll be great”; end at 0:29 after “see y’all soon” and before she tries and fails to eat it)']

Comment: list2 = ['(end at 1:55 after “running joke in this house”)', '(end at 4:17 after “see what we’ve got”) (end at 0:48ish after she takes the bite and says “mmm”) (start at 0:10 with “so this’ll be great”; end at 0:29 after “see y’all soon” and before she tries and fails to eat it)']